# Cannot resolve symbol 'Firebase'

Tags: firebase, android-studio-2.3

I'm using android studio version 2.3 and have connected firebase. but an error is occurring stating that the symbol firebase cannot be resolved. please help me through this.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your build.gradle :
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

Answer (score 1):

In one of my classes, I had this:

```
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Constraint;
```

Android Studio was highlighting the word `firebase` in red and the error message was: `Cannot resolve symbol 'firebase'`. The solution was to go to the `dependencies {}` section in `app/build.gradle` and add this:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
```

The error was fixed.